# How to subscribe to Events of Dependency Injected Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I’m using entity Framework Core to create crud services in my asp.net core application. My crud services have events and handlers like OnCreated, OnUpdated.

These events should be able to call other crud services as well.

How can this be achieved?

Here's how I'm injecting my CRUD services:

```
services.AddTransient<IRoleManager, RoleManager>();
        services.AddTransient<IOfficeManager, OfficeManager>();
        services.AddTransient<IProjectManager, ProjectManager>();
```

Here is example of my crud one of my CRUD Services:

```
public class ProjectManager : IProjectManager
{
    protected AppDbContext Db;

    public ProjectManager(AppDbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects()
    {
        return Db.Projects;
    }

    public Project CreateProject (Project project)
    {
        Project Project = Db.Projects.Add(project).Entity;
        Db.SaveChanges();
        OnProjectCreated(Project);
        return Project;
    }

    public Project UpdateProject (Project project)
    {
        Project Project = Db.Projects.Update(project).Entity;
        Db.SaveChanges();
        OnProjectUpdated(Project);
        return Project;
    }

    public Project DeleteProject (Project project)
    {
        Db.Projects.Remove(project);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        OnProjectDeleted(project);
        return project;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ProjectManagerEventArgs> ProjectCreated;
    public event EventHandler<ProjectManagerEventArgs> ProjectUpdated;
    public event EventHandler<ProjectManagerEventArgs> ProjectDeleted;

    protected virtual void OnProjectCreated(Project project)
    {
        ProjectCreated?.Invoke(this, new ProjectManagerEventArgs(project));
    }

    protected virtual void OnProjectUpdated(Project project)
    {
        ProjectUpdated?.Invoke(this, new ProjectManagerEventArgs(project));
    }

    protected virtual void OnProjectDeleted(Project project)
    {
        ProjectDeleted?.Invoke(this, new ProjectManagerEventArgs(project));
    }
}
```

I can subscribe this way...

```
services.AddTransient(sp =>
    {
        AppDbContext dependency = sp.GetService<AppDbContext>();
        ProjectManager target = new ProjectManager(dependency);
        target.ProjectCreated += new ProjectManagerListener().OnProjectCreated;
        return (IProjectManager)target;
    });
```

but that way feels very sloppy, and prevents my Handler/Listener from accessing other CRUD services.

How can I use events with DI?

CODE FOR LISTENER

```
public class ProjectManagerListener
{
    private readonly IClaimManager ClaimManager;
    private readonly IRoleManager RoleManager;

    public ProjectManagerListener(IClaimManager claimManager, IRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        ClaimManager = claimManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public void OnProjectCreated(object source, ProjectManagerEventArgs ProjectEventArgs)
    {
        foreach (Role role in RoleManager.GetRoles())
        {
            ClaimManager.CreateClaim(new ProjectRoleClaim() { ProjectId = ProjectEventArgs.Project.Id, RoleId = role.Id });
        }
    }
}
```

CODE FOR LISTENER INJETION

```
services.AddTransient(sp =>
        {
            AppDbContext dependency = sp.GetService<AppDbContext>();
            IClaimManager ClaimManager = sp.GetService<IClaimManager>();
            IRoleManager RoleManager = sp.GetService<IRoleManager>();
            ProjectManager target = new ProjectManager(dependency);
            target.ProjectCreated += new ProjectManagerListener(ClaimManager, RoleManager).OnProjectCreated;
            return (IProjectManager)target;
        });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve in the end ? Why do you need to create an instance of `ProjectManagerListener` inside the DI registration of service  `IProjectManager` ?

Comment: Perhaps I want to send an email when a project is created.  Any event that i want to happen when any of my crud items is created, updated, deleted, etc.

Comment: You already have an event just subscribe to it in a constructor of a service that consumes `IProjectManager`. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: As shown i can subscribe to the event in a very sloppy way in startup.cs.  But I may need access to the other crud services.  Say I am constructing an email, and need to gather more information from the other CRUD services that relate to passed object.

Comment: Just inject the Project Manager, in addition to any other services needed to handle the event. Subscribe to the event with a closure

Comment: Perhaps the problem is `ProjectManagerListener`? You haven't shown that class but it's not clear Wyatt can't simply depend on the project manager.

Comment: Well, if I am not mistaken we try to initially subscribe with an event handler to event inside of a service that we register for dependency injection with `services.AddTransient`. If we just want that our service runs `ProjectManagerListener.OnProjectCreated` every time the `OnProjectCreated` event occurs then we can pass an instance of `ProjectManagerListener` into ctor of the service and subscribe to event there or we can remove the event all together and call the event handler directly.

Comment: I tried that.  Didn’t work, never calls the listener

Comment: Well, *It didn't work* doesn't provide a lot of information... Did you use multi-threading ?

Comment: Adding code now for project manager listener

Answer (score 4):

One way to make this work is to create services for the event publishing/listening instead of using C# events. Then you can utilize DI with these services. In its *absolutely crudest* form, you need the following elements:

Events:

```
public class ProjectCreatedEvent
{
    public int ProjectId { get; }

    public ProjectCreatedEvent(int projectId)
    {
        ProjectId = projectId;
    }
}
```

These will likely be immutable POCOs.

Listeners:

```
public interface IListener
{
}

public interface IListener<T> : IListener
{
    void HandleMessage(T message);
}

public class ProjectCreatedEventListener : IListener<ProjectCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IClaimManager _claimManager;

    public ProjectCreatedEventListener(IClaimManager claimManager)
    {
        _claimManager = claimManager;
    }

    public void HandleMessage(ProjectCreatedEvent message)
    {
        _claimManager.CreateClaim(message.ProjectId);
    }
}
```

Since these will be registered with the DI container they can easily inject dependencies.

A dispatcher:

```
public interface IDispatcher
{
    void Publish<T>(T message);
}

public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IListener> _listeners;

    public Dispatcher(IEnumerable<IListener> listeners)
    {
        _listeners = listeners;
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message)
    {
        foreach (var listener in _listeners.OfType<IListener<T>>())
        {
            listener.HandleMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This just injects all of the listeners and then provides a way to publish a message to it's listeners.

And you would then publish the events like:

```
public class ProjectManager : IProjectManager
{
    private readonly IDispatcher _dispatcher;

    public ProjectManager(IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public void CreateProject(string name)
    {
        // Do the CRUD...
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating project '{name}'");
        _dispatcher.Publish(new ProjectCreatedEvent(43));
    }
}
```

And here's a working example of this all wired up in DI:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<IProjectManager, ProjectManager>()
        .AddTransient<IClaimManager, ClaimManager>()
        .AddTransient<IListener<ProjectCreatedEvent>, ProjectCreatedEventListener>()
        .AddTransient<IListener>(sp => sp.GetService<IListener<ProjectCreatedEvent>>())
        .AddTransient<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IProjectManager>();

    service.CreateProject("My project.");
}
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

Comment: This was a solid answer devNull, but it didn't quite solve my problem.  I think the issue is a race condition, but it's hard to tell because the browser just closes and the app stops with no errors.

RoleManager has a dependency on ClaimManager, ProjectManager, and OfficeManager.

ProjectManager has a dependency on ClaimManager and RoleManager.

OfficeManager has a dependency on ClaimManager and RoleManager.

Comment: Nice solution @devNull . One question, what exactly is the need for the empty IListener interface?

Comment: And how could the solution be extended if the ProjectManager would have to handle several events (for instance also a ProjectRenamed event) ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using SQL Triggers:

using EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers from Nuget

In my Models (example Role):

```
static Role()
    {
        Triggers<Role>.Inserted += e =>
        {
            e.Context.Add(new RoleClaim() { RoleId = e.Entity.Id });
            IEnumerable<Office> offices = e.Context.Set<Office>();

            foreach(Office office in offices)
            {
                e.Context.Add(new OfficeRoleClaim() { Office = office, Role = e.Entity });
            }

            IEnumerable<Project> projects = e.Context.Set<Project>();

            foreach (Project project in projects)
            {
                e.Context.Add(new ProjectRoleClaim() { Project = project, Role = e.Entity });
            }

            e.Context.SaveChanges();
        };
    }
```

And in the DbContext:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return this.SaveChangesWithTriggers(base.SaveChanges, acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: true);
    }
```